# Get the selected value on change in select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I have to make a shop. Its almost done but I am stuck to let the customer change the amount in the cart of the products and to let the price change dynamically.

I made a select-tag with 10 options, where the chosen amount is selected. I want the user to be able to click the select, choose an other amount and to calculate the price in live preview. But I cant figure out how to select all the select-tags and put a click event on every option.

I tried like this:

```
<select class="st" name="">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
   <option>4</option>
   <option>5</option>
</select>
```

and my jquery:

```
var st = $('.st');

st.change(function(){
var str = "";
$( ".st option:selected").each(function() {
    str = $(this).text();
    console.log(str);
  });
})
```

but with that I am getting the selected one from every select-tag. I want it to just console me the selected one in the select-tag where I have clicked. How can I do that?

Comment: `Ich want it to just log me the selected one in the select-tag where i have clicked.How can i do that?` can you elaborate on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the value for the current `<select>` directly, by doing this:

```
var st = $('.st');

st.change(function(){
    // $(this) references the current <select>
    console.log($(this).val());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop re-grabs every `.st`, instead of using `this` so that it targets the clicked object.

```
st.change(function(){
    var str = "";
    $(this).each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":selected")) { //add if check to see if option is selected
            str = $(this).text();
            console.log(str);
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: thx, but this wouldnt work. I forgot to mention that its not one select-tag its many. It depends on how much products are in the cart. so i have at least one select tag to unlimited. thats why i am selecting the class (to select all the select-tags). but now i need to choose every option of every select-tag...

Answer (score 0):

In case of getting TEXT instead of VALUE, below code would help:

```
$('select').on('change', function(e){
   console.log($(e.currentTarget).find(":selected").text())
})
```